# Can I validate and deny requests based on a requirement that we're sent a content-length header?

Tags: http, http-headers, haproxy, content-length

We have a service that we want to validate and deny requests for, based on whether or not the request contains the `Content-Length` header. I was able to find this:

`capture request header Content-Length len 10`

But from what I can tell in the docs, this just enables logging for `Content-Length`, not actually forcing it to be present. We were hoping to be able to (a) validate that the `Content-Length` header is present, and (b) deny requests that exceed a given length (10MB).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hdr_val()` function to get HTTP header values.

**Example:**

```
acl greater_than_10MB hdr_val(content-length) gt 10240
http-request deny if greater_than_10MB
```